# Puppeteer - How to get Page from ElementHandle

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

When i have a reference to a Puppeteers ElemntHandle is there a method to get the Page instance were this element belongs to (or was previously retrieved from via `$(selector)`)? something similar to [elementHandle.contentFrame()](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v10.0.0&show=api-elementhandlecontentframe)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind using undocumented properties:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  const handle = await page.$('body');

  console.log(handle.executionContext().frame()._frameManager._page === page);
} catch (err) { console.error(err); } finally { await browser.close(); }
```

Comment: if there is no other solution, then i take what i can get. and this works

Comment: speaking of undocumented API, @vsemozhebuty, do you know any possibility to check if a Puppeteer.Page is running in chrome or firefox nightly?

Comment: @user2520818 Try `await page.browser().version()` or `page.browser().process().spawnfile`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. (`.version()` returns `Chrome/92.0.4512.0` / `Headless Firefox`)